# call a function that it's name is like a given string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of size 2: [3,8].

I want to add onclick for any id that I have by the following:

instead of: `$("#a1").click(function(){ a3(); });`, I want to do something like:

```
var a = "a" + arr[0].toString + "();"; // 'a = a3();'

$("#a1").click(function(){ a });
```

there is an option to call a function by a string?

in other words, I have a string: var func = "abc";

how can I call the func: abc(); by the string of func?

any help appreciated!

Comment: not `eval()`, never `eval()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bracket notation:

```
function abc() {
   //...
}

var func = 'abc';

window[func](); //calls abc()
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `[]`. Here is a solution which should work at any scope:

```
function a1() {alert('a1');}
var context = this;
$("#a1").click(function(){ context[this.id](); });
```